# Check multiple column if match value in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have already know the rows and columns after matching the condition as follows:
My data-set:

```
Power | Channel | Speed | Speed2 | Speed3 
50    | 1       | 400   | 200    | 100
50    | 6       | 400   | 500    |  80
50    | 6       | 400   | 500    | 800
```

and I want to create a new column where it matches my condition where if all column speed `>= 100`, return those rows. For example:

```
Power | Channel | Speed | Speed2 | Speed3 | Flag
50    | 1       | 400   | 200    | 100    |  1
50    | 6       | 400   | 500    |  80    |  1
```

I already knows the return rows and columns using this code:

```
which(blk13fullpower <= 100, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

which gives the output of:

```
         row col 
   [1,]   1   1 
   [2,]   2   1
   [3,]   3   1
   [4,]   4   1
   [5,]   5   1
   [6,]   6   1
   [7,]   7   1
```

However, I do not know how to flag my dataframe based on my results.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Try `df[rowSums(df[grep("Speed",names(df))]<100)==0,]`.

Comment: @nicola it returns me all the NA values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this

```
cols <- grep("^Speed", names(df))
df[rowSums(df[cols] <= 100, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ]
```

with `apply`

```
df[apply(df[cols] <= 100, 1, any), ]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Speed")), any_vars(. <= 100))
```

If you want to add a new column with `flag = 1` with base R solutions you can use `transform`

```
transform(df[rowSums(df[cols] <= 100, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ], flag = 1)
```

or `mutate` with `dplyr`

```
df %>%  
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Speed")), any_vars(. <= 100)) %>%
   mutate(flag = 1)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply but however all of my original values in the dataframe change to NA and it flags everything. What could go wrong?

Comment: @Team9 you might have `NA` values in the data. How do you want to deal with them? If you have 5 `Speed` columns and for a particular row you have 2 `NA` values in them and rest of them are above 100 would you like to select that row or ignore it?

Comment: I would like to treat those NA as zeros. But however if one of the column is below 100, i would like to select that whole row

Comment: One of the column or all the column above 100? In the shared example why the 3rd row is not selected?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo i made earlier. I meant columns **below** 100. Which means i want to check on all the columns below 100, create a new column called "flag" and flag them if Speed <= 100

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah , do you by any chance know how to solve this problem? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522769/plot-graph-based-on-sliderinput-date-range)

Answer (score 1):

Try ifelse

```
blk13fullpower$flag <- ifelse ( blk13fullpower$Speed >100 & blk13fullpower$Speed2 > 100 & blk13fullpower$Speed3 >100 , 1 , 0)
```

Its easier if you provide some data using the dput command.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but however this only works for few columns. What if i have 300 columns to check?