# Plot graph based on sliderInput date range in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to plot my line graph using "ggplot2" package that follows according to the input date from the slider.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Date       | Blk 6 | Blk 6 | Blk 6 | Blk 6   | Total
           | Lvl1  | Lvl1  | Lvl1  | Lvl2
           | AP01  | AP02  | AP03  | AP01
---------------------------------------------
2018-09-03 | 500   | 200   | 1000  | 2000    | 3700
2018-09-04 | 100   | 400   | 6000  | 3000    | 9500
2018-09-05 | 300   | 800   | 3000  | 4000    | 8100
```

Here's what i have come out with:

```
ui.R

conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs==5",
                     sliderInput("DatesMerge", "Dates:",
                                 min = as.Date("2018-09-03","%Y-%m-%d"),
                                 max = as.Date("2019-05-30","%Y-%m-%d"),
                                 value=as.Date(c("2018-08-01","2019-01-01" )),timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d"))


server.R
# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

#plot the freq
          output$plot <- renderPlot({


            #select Jan - May 2019 dataset for blk 13
             blk3plot <- ggplot(data=blk3, aes(x=input$DatesMerge, y=Total)) + geom_line(color="blue") + ggtitle("Before: Blk 3 Traffic(Between 3/9/2018-30/5/2019) ") +
              ylab("Traffic (Mbps)")

            return(blk3plot)
          })

}
```

I'm not sure how to edit my ggplot according to my slider date format. I get this error when i run...Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (270): x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter your data using the `input$DatesMerge` which is a vector of length two.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

#plot the freq
output$plot <- renderPlot({

#select Jan - May 2019 dataset for blk 

blk3plot <- blk3 %>%
 filter(Date >= input$DatesMerge[1], Date <= input$DateMerge[2]) %>%
 ggplot( aes(x=Date, y=Total)) +
 geom_line(color="blue") +
 ggtitle("Before: Blk 3 Traffic(Between 3/9/2018-30/5/2019) ") +
 ylab("Traffic (Mbps)")

return(blk3plot)
          })

}
```

I do not see the `Total` variable in your data frame, but I suppose there is one.